# Mechanize - Not able to parse POST form for automated submission

Tags: python, forms, submit, mechanize

:-)

I am trying to download a page, fill out a form on the page and submit it. I like python and came across mechanize. I can download the webpage successfully, verify that the page has 2 forms in it, however, mechanize won't recognize the second form (method POST) even though I can verify that the webpage data downloaded by mechanize clearly contains the 2nd form. Hence, I cannot even proceed to modify the values and submit the form I am interested in. I am on Python 2.6.1 on OS X 10.6.8. Any advice is very appreciated.

My code

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # no robots
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/6.0 (X11; U; i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 OS X 10.2 Firefox/3.0.1')]
url = 'http://www.abcd.com/test.html'
response = br.open(url)
```

I can verify using a response.read() or get_data() that there are two forms, like below

```
<form id="lookupFormX" action="/lookup/" onSubmit="return submitLookupForm('lookupForm', 'download');" method="GET">

                <label style="font-weight:normal; font-size:85%; margin-right:5px;">View a Site Report </label>
                <input type="hidden" name="facet" style="margin-right:2px; font-weight:normal; font-size:85%;" value="sitereport" readonly/>

                <input style="margin-right:2px; font-weight:normal; font-size:85%;" name="q" type="text" id="railtext_v11pt" value="e.g. yahoo.com"
                        onfocus="clearDefaultNote(this,'e.g. yahoo.com');"
                        onblur="addDefaultNote(this,'e.g. yahoo.com');" />
                <a style="margin-right:10px;" href="#" onclick="submitLookupForm('lookupFormX');"><img src="/images/nav_right.gif" /></a>
            </form>

<br>
<FORM action="userfeedbackpost.html" id="friendForm" name="friendForm" method="post">
<TABLE id="userfeedbacktable" BORDER=0 style="padding:left:0px; margin-left:0px;">
    <TR>
        <TD style="width:200px;padding-left:10px">Your Name:</TD>
        <TD style="width:200px" ><input name="your_name" type="text" SIZE=35/></TD>

        <TD style="width:250px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px">Your E-mail:</TD>
        <TD style="width:140px" ><input name="your_email" type="text" SIZE=35/></TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- <TR></TR> -->
    <TR>
        <TD style="width:200px;padding-left:10px">Subject:</TD>
        <TD colspan="3" ><input name="subject" type="text" style="width:648px" SIZE=106/></TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- <TR></TR> -->
    <TR>
        <TD style="width:200px;padding-left:10px">URL this concerns:</TD>
        <TD colspan="3" ><input name="url" type="text" style="width:648px" SIZE=106/></TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- <TR></TR> -->
    <TR>
        <TD style="width:200px;padding-left:10px">User ID:</TD>
        <TD style="width:200px" ><input name="test_id" type="text" SIZE=35/></TD>

        <TD style="width:250px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px">Type of inquiry:</TD>
        <TD style="width:140px" >
            <SELECT name="type" id="type" style="width:262px" onchange="makeSelection()">
                <OPTION value="Choose">Choose One</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Bug report">Report an error</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Helpful Information">Send us a suggestion</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Other">Other</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- <TR></TR> -->
    <TR id="infoPanel" style="display:none">
        <TD style="width:200px;padding-left:10px">Facet in question:</TD>
        <TD style="width:200px" >
            <SELECT name="facet" style="width:263px" id="facet">
                <OPTION selected value="Choose">Choose One</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Annoyances">Annoyances</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Downloads">Downloads</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Links">Links</OPTION>
           </SELECT>
       </TD>

       <TD style="width:250px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px">Are you the site owner?:</TD>
       <TD style="width:140px" >
           <input type="radio" id="siteowner_yes" name="siteowner" value="Yes">&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <input type="radio" id="siteowner_no" name="siteowner" value="No" checked>&nbsp;No
       </TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- <TR></TR> -->
    <TR>
        <TD style="width:200px;padding-left:10px" >Your Message:</TD>
        <TD colspan=3><textarea class=userfeedbackTA NAME=message ROWS=12 COLS=80 style="width:646px;"></textarea></TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- <TR></TR> -->
</TABLE>

<br/><br/> <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('friendForm').submit();" class="btnOrangeLrg"><span>Send Your Feedback or Question.</span></a><br/>
<br/><br/> P.S. We will use the information above only to help provide you feedback. This information will not be used for any other purpose.

</FORM>
```

mechanize only shows the following:

```
Form name: None
<GET http://www.test.com/lookup/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(facet=sitereport) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(q=e.g. yahoo.com)>>
```

when I use the following code

```
for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form
```

My Question:
- How can I get access to the second form? (using nr=1 gave me an error)

Edit:

I tried this version out too, same result, 2nd form will not show up:

```
request = mechanize.Request(url)
request.add_header("User-agent", "Mozilla/6.0 (X11; U; i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 OS X 10.2 Firefox/3.0.1")
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
response.close()

for form in forms:
  print form
```

Edit 2

I also tried to modify my code to look like this:

```
# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [
('Cookie','mbox=PC#1327356910232-537677#1410633293|check#true#1347561353|session#1347561287712-498080#1347563153; s_cc=true; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_nr=1347561671754-Repeat'),\
('Accept-Charset','ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'),\
('Accept-Encoding','gzip,deflate,sdch'),\
('Accept-Language','en-US,en'),\
('Cache-Control','max-age=0'),\
('Connection','keep-alive'),\
('Referer','http://www.siteadvisor.com'),\
('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1')
]
```

I picked up the header values from my browser and tried to plug them in the mechanize browser instance. Yet I only can see the 1 form.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue to you, and I found that modifying my headers and including `RobustFactory()` to deal with 'bad' HTML solved the problem.

```
`br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6')]`
```

This was after a lot a fiddling around with them. This solution works for the general case as well as the specific URL I was using, but adding:

```
br.addheaders.append(['Accept-Encoding', 'gzip'])
```

may be necessary if the URL you are trying to access is GZipped. You can check if this is the case here: http://checkgzipcompression.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should've provided the url, since if I put your given html with forms in `text` variable this happens:

```
In [61]: forms = mech.ParseString(text, 'fake') # imported mechanize as mech

In [62]: for form in forms: print form; print '-'*5
   ....: 
<GET fake application/x-www-form-urlencoded>
-----
<GET /lookup/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(facet=sitereport) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(q=e.g. yahoo.com)>>
-----
<friendForm POST userfeedbackpost.html application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(your_name=)>
  <TextControl(your_email=)>
  <TextControl(subject=)>
  <TextControl(url=)>
  <TextControl(test_id=)>
  <SelectControl(type=[*Choose, Bug report, Helpful Information, Other])>
  <SelectControl(facet=[*Choose, Annoyances, Downloads, Links])>
  <RadioControl(siteowner=[Yes, *No])>
  <TextareaControl(message=)>>
-----
```

First is default one (added by the parse) ignore it. So nice happy two forms.